# Cassandra log4j Vulnerability exception

Tags: log4j

We are using apache Cassandra 3.11.7 running on native kubernetes cluster. Is it vulnerable to the log4j security exception?

Comment: Consider posting this on security.stackexchange.com, see [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/258058/is-xcode-vulnerable-due-to-log4j) similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you find a list of affected software. Cassandra is not in the list. https://github.com/cisagov/log4j-affected-db